# Using $.getJSON method and PHP

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am trying to use the $.getJSON  function to return data. I have the following html file
named page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    $.getJSON("json-data.php",function(result){
     alert(result);
    });

  });

});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div id="showdata"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have the following PHP file named json-data.php:

```
<?php
//request data from the database
//code here to connect to database and get the data you want

/* Example JSON format 
{
  "item1": "I love jquery4u",
  "item2": "You love jQuery4u",
  "item3": "We love jQuery4u"
}
*/
$item1 = "I love jquery4u";
$item2 = "You love jquery4u";
$item3 = "We love jquery4u";
//return in JSON format
echo "{";
echo "item1: ", json_encode($item1), "\n";
echo "item2: ", json_encode($item2), "\n";
echo "item3: ", json_encode($item3), "\n";
echo "}";
?>
```

I am only trying to use the alert function to see the data in the PHP file, however it does not work. Anyone know why?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Response JSON format incorrect, do like that: `echo 'item1: "', json_encode($item1), '"\n';`

Answer (score 1):

It's because your json is in invalid format:

```
$items = array("item1" => "I love jquery4u", "item2" => "You love jquery4u", "item3" => "jquery4u");

echo json_encode($items);
```